# JSoup execute method slow on linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, performance, jsoup

I'm having an issue with the performance of the http request within JSoup.

On the development pc (Windows 7) it works great.
When I deploy the same service on a Suse Linux enterprise server, the http requests is much slower. 
The difference is +- 15 seconds. (15 seconds slower on linux)

```
JSoup version 1.7.3.
Java version : 1.7.0_51.
```

The JVM parameters are exactly the same on both machines.

My call:

```
 Connection.Response response =   Jsoup.connect(urlWrk).data(headerDataMap).cookies(cookieStore).method(httpMethod).userAgent(userAgent).timeout(requestTimeout).execute();
```

I'm using the POST method.

I started a `tcpdump session` and it looks like the execute method hangs a few seconds before it actually executes the http request.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The website I'm trying to scrape is an ASP website on IIS. Looks like it has something to do with the session handling in IIS. The creation of the session/viewstate takes long. But I still don't understand why this is slower when the client is linux. I use the same useragent.

Answer (score 0):

You might have slower DNS resolution in your Linux box. Check the dns servers in /etc/resolv.conf. Maybe the first one is not responding and it times out before trying with the second.

Comment: I've checked this. DNS resolution is not the problem.